# Firebase Authentication on iOS

Tags: firebase, authentication

All of a sudden my iOS app will not authenticate with Firebase using email/password.

The error I get is:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000d140f0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=4 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    displayName = "";
    email = "k@k.com";
    expiresIn = 3600;
    idToken = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjU0OGYzZjk4N2IxNzMxOWZlZDhjZDc2ODNmNTIyNWEyOTY0YzY5OWQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dstIl19LCJzaWduX2luX3Byb3ZpZGVyIjoicGFzc3dvcmQifX0.vURIA_hAn1imIocwiV8quN5QXAdnmNrcuVB0Wl3EWUcgcNCseIwORspnpXF4M3rg1dlr7LyxIZEqpefjRd86TgJyAvI7ibWYoSSYHNdw1iURvwLUyOfRdyyxnUhCYlCbnBokaL3EqWVM4rV_jqxdhIBRZOWsna-0Gz-8Lua0k5JdrNjSTajnuEsjMc-cV9ec7_83VFlCjz0pHhVmIalQi7I7YA8MYi021sq3FhqC9kXU88_pGcdTEboMy12tHtJd19kwwyQ3xXIHw--eKkxici4ZEIt_yv4uVXz1ZHLDE8dDl8T4zDEmW_Yh4jMnc0AbUpjuhywn5TNAthbsVgdn4w";
    kind = "identitytoolkit#SignInWithPasswordResponse";
    localId = LVxz2oxAvrU1qOAOA8BPNhifqIB3;
    refreshToken = "AEu4IL1Vn0O9mBkt-vbWkxp1XZ3R1uYEAxFz7Ivwhr9B0T9LFkaRV4i_VQmU0zHjYkCM4OX_Zc1yPw8MlAc6V4sYYkTxkSiLFWH9x3osWf2f0Kj-kRZJJ01Hi5YUCPiD4Jb3u4dSY-sskkAHyV12USbNcKyV45yHoC8LQj4_PlbRuy7piIl3Dv6VjsE6kw";
    registered = 1;
}}}}
```

Nothing has changed code-wise and this just started a few days ago on all iOS devices and older versions of the app. Android versions log in fine. I've tried adding new users, and new databases. The pod versions of Firebase are up to date.

Comment: As a test, did you re-downloading the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file? It will probably have no affect.

Comment: Yes, I did and it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved by upgrading the Firebase libraries. However, doing it via pods broke the build and I ended up having to manually include the Firebase libraries.

Comment: What version(s) of the Firebase libraries did you upgrade to?  And what version were you using previously?